# Wrong function resolution in template when using inheritance

Tags: c++

This code prints

```
non-template
template
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <type_traits>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct A {
    void g1();
};

struct B : A {
    void g2();
};

void f(A& a)
{
    cout << "non-template" << endl;
}


template<typename T>
void f(T&& t)
{
    cout << "template" << endl;
}

void A::g1()
{
    f(*this);
}

void B::g2()
{
    f(*this);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    
    A a;
    a.g1();
    
    B b;
    b.g2(); // ????
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Why and how make it print

```
non-template
non-template
```

?

Comment: Because the non-template `f` takes in a `A&`, the template taking in a `B&` is more specialized.

Comment: But aren't non-templated functions prioritized over template functions?

Comment: Yes, for something like `A&`, the template and the non-template could do the job -> non-template getting called. But `B&` just fits better than `A&` for an `B&`.

Comment: Does it resolve the problem if I add SFINAE to block any `X&` where `X` inherit from `A` in the template function?

Comment: [Overload resolution rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) specify that l-value to r-value conversion counts as "exact match", whereas "conversion from derived class to base" is "conversion". So the B& to B&& is a better match than B& to A&, and the preference for non-templated functions over templated functions only kicks in if the match is otherwise equally good.

Comment: @jxh this is just an example, the `A::g()` and `B::g()` aren't related

Comment: @nathan there is no rvalue conversion.  Forwarding references make `T&&` into `A&` exactly

Comment: Ah, I love how many different uses there are for `&` in C++. Thanks for clarification. An even more exact match, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non template beats template when there is otherwise a tie.

But for `*this` in `B::b2`, the template generates a `(B&)` signature, and the non-template a `(A&)`, and `B&` is a better match.  No tie.

For `A::g1`, it is `(A&)` vs `(A&)`, a tie, so non-template wins.

Overload resolution can't do what you want.  You can manually dispatch, say in the template, where if the `T&` is descended from `A` you cast and call.  Or a myriad of other manual hacks, like `requires(decay<T> is not derived from A)` (pseudo code) in the template overload.  Again, manual dispatching.  (in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) the technique is requires; prior sfinae is needed).